# Find a system of equations which describes space $V=lin\{(-2,1,0,-3),(2,-1,1,3)\} \subset \mathbb R^{4}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I think that I know how to do this task but I need know that I have right. This is my idea: I create matrix with vectors from lin and after elementary matrix I have: $$\begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & -0,5 & 0 & -1,5
\end{bmatrix}$$ Then I think that the matrix show that I have: $(x,y,z,w)=z(0,0,1,0)+x(1,-0,5,0,-1,5)$ and my system of equations is: $ \begin{cases} x=-0,5y-1,5w\\ z=0 \end{cases} $

Comment: What's lin? Is it just span?

Comment: You made a calculation error. It should be $+1,5$.

Comment: Yes, lin is a span

Comment: Both points in your basis must be in the space. Is that consistent with your system?

Answer (score 1):

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  -2&2&x\\
  1&-1&y\\
  0&1&z\\
  -3&3&t
\end{array}
\right]$$
Using Gauss-Jordan elimination we get:

$$ \left[
\begin{array}{cc|c}
  1&0&-\cfrac{x}{2}+z\\
  0&1&z\\
  0&0&y+\cfrac{x}{2}\\
  0&0&-\cfrac{t}{3}+\cfrac{x}{2}
\end{array}
\right]$$

What you are looking for is the set of equasions that are in the form of [something]=0. In this case we get: $\begin{cases}
0=-\cfrac{t}{3}+\cfrac{x}{2}\\
0=y+\cfrac{x}{2}& 
\end{cases}$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

All points in your space are of the form

$$
\alpha(-2,1,0,-3) + \beta(2,-1,1,3)
$$
for some $\alpha, \beta \in \mathbb R$.

So you just need to solve

$$\alpha(-2,1,0,-3) + \beta(2,-1,1,3) = (x,y,z,w)$$